# Toggling mouse keys in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, mouse, keys, numlock

I have enabled mouse keys in **Nniversal Access -> Pointing and Clicking**

I've read that <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>numlock</kbd> is suppose to toggle the mouse keys, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I would like to be able to use mouse keys and be able to toggle them off so I can also use the keypad.